# after upgrading to .net 5, dotnet cli is unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json due to SSL connection

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-5

I was on Windows 10 working with .net core 3.1. After .net 5 was launched, I upgraded to the new version immediately. I updated my Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.8. Everything worked well in Visual Studio, but when I tried to update dotnet-ef in dotnet cli,

`dotnet tool update dotnet-ef -g`

I got this error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\eip3wn3x.eys\restore.csproj]

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\eip3wn3x.eys\restore.csproj]

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :    Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. [C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Temp\eip3wn3x.eys\restore.csproj]

> The tool package could not be restored.
> Tool 'dotnetsay' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.

> For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool

I also tried to install the dotnetsay but got the same error:

`dotnet tool install dotnetsay -g`

Before upgrading to .net 5, I was able to install dotnet-ef 3.1 and everything was fine. I guess the issue mighe be caused by an invalid certificate on my local, but not sure, and I don't know which certificate is used for nuget.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with the same setup (win 10, vs 2019 16.8, .net 3.1 -> .net 5.0). For me the solution was to set a registry value as specified by [this github comment by wfurt](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40679#issuecomment-673675486).

**The solution copied from that comment:**

Set the value `Enabled` (Dword) to 0 under the key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client`

[This comment by Gnbrkm41](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40679#issuecomment-673974611) provides a powershell script to accomplish the same.